# Acceder a checkbox de una tabla php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo acceder a los elementos de tipo `checkbox` y me valla sumando en un `input` el numero de las filas seleccionas tal como se puede observar en la imagen.

Mi tabla:

```
<tbody>
                                <?php if(!empty($tarimas)): ?>
                                    <?php foreach($tarimas as $tarimas): ?>
                                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                        <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tarimas->id;?>" name='inputseleccion[]'><?php echo $tarimas->id; ?></td>
                                        <td><span class="badge bg-green"><?php echo $tarimas->peso; ?></span> kgs</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $tarimas->cajas; ?> cajas</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                              <input type="checkbox" value="" name='inputselect[]' class="chkseleccion"> Añadir
                                            </label>
                                            </div>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </tbody>
```

Supongo que es con javascript o jquery pero como puedo acceder y saber si se ha cambiado a checked? con que me digan como acceder y traer los resultados de la fila checkeada me ayudarian bastante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar Jquery:

Paso 1: Incluir la libreria antes de cerrar el contenido del body de la pagina:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Paso 2: Debes agregar la siguiente estructura a tu tabla ya que para tomar el valor de los campos de Peso de Tarima y Cajas de tarima de tu tabla, se deben agregar clases y elementos separadores a los valores de estas filas. Para este ejemplo he agregado la clase *kilogramo* y la clase *cant-cajas* para poder tomar el valor de los campos.

Tu tabla:

```
<tbody>
    <?php if(!empty($tarimas)): ?>
    <?php foreach($tarimas as $tarimas): ?>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tarimas->id;?>" name='inputseleccion[]'>
            <?php echo $tarimas->id; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="badge bg-green kilogramo">
                <?php echo $tarimas->peso; ?>
            </span> kgs</td>
        <td>
            <span class="cant-cajas"><?php echo $tarimas->cajas; ?></span> cajas</td>
        <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name='inputselect[]' class="chkseleccion"> Añadir
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

Paso 3: Incluir el siguiente script luego de jquery del *paso 1*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var verificarTotal = function () {
        var $seleccionados = $(".chkseleccion:checked"),
            $cajas = $("#tuInputTotalCaja"),
            $kilogramos = $("#tuInputTotalKilogramos"),
            totalCajas = 0,
            totalKilogramos = 0;

        $.each($seleccionados, function (indice, fila) {

            if ($(fila).is(':checked')) {
                totalCajas += parseInt($(fila).closest('tr').find('.cant_cajas').html());
                totalKilogramos += parseInt($(fila).closest('tr').find('.kilogramo').html());
            }
        });

        $cajas.val(totalCajas);
        $kilogramos.val(totalKilogramos);
    };

    $(".chkseleccion").on('click', function (e) {
        verificarTotal();
    });

    verificarTotal();
});
```

Comment: la selección funciona bien pero me muestra el numero de inputs seleccionados.  Como puedo sumar las columnas, como en la imagen, si te das cuenta esta seleccionado el primero y paso el numero de kgs.

Comment: Modificaré la respuesta teniendo en cuenta esto que citas, de igual manera solo te incluire el ejemplo utilizando jquery.

Comment: me funciono, gracias por tu tiempo bro! lml

Comment: Oye delcio, puse un input pero tipo _hidden_ para el envio POST como array, pero como puedo pasar _1 o  0_ si se checkea el checkbox?

Comment: Todo llamada a javascript se debe hacer al final del documento, no al inicio -1

Comment: Hola @AlfredoPaz cierto sin embargo la solución al problema fue la que el usuario marcó como correcta, eso que mencionas es una buena practica. Lo tomaré para futuras respuestas.

Comment: @ManuelMorales para pasar 1 o 0 si se chequea el checkbox debes modificar tu checkbox por lo siguiente:

 <input type="checkbox" value="" name='inputselect[]' class="chkseleccion" value="1"> Añadir

Cuando recibas el desde tu clase PHP, tienes que validar que este llegando el valor 1, de lo contrario lo seteas a 0.

Comment: @DelcioManuelPolancoPadilla solo haz la correción en tu respuesta indicandole la observación que te hago

Comment: @AlfredoPaz he actualizado la respuesta, recordar que no es al final del documento, segun las buenas practicas se debe incluir al final antes de cerrar la etiqueta body como se indica en esta respuesta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488298/where-in-the-html-file-should-jquery-and-bootstrap-be-placed

Comment: puse _$(fila).closest('tr').find('.inputcheck_x').value('1');_ dentro del if, me lo cambia perfecto, pero al darle discheck no me cambia a cero a pesar de poner un else.